# Determine whether a YouTube video cannot be embedded in a specific site

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

[This YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kmeFXjjGfk) can be embedded into most sites (e.g., Stackoverflow), but it cannot be embedded into [Rap Genius](http://rapgenius.com). You can try it yourself by pasting the embed code in to Rap Genius with firebug. You'll see this:

[image]

I need a way to detect whether a video is specifically blocked from Rap Genius.

Note that this is different from checking whether a video cannot be embedded *anywhere* – i.e., if you GET `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&q=_kmeFXjjGfk`, you'll see that in the JSON response, `data.items[0].accessControl.embed == 'allowed'`

One clue: before the video starts playing, the player makes a request to a URL that looks like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=_kmeFXjjGfk&el=embedded&ps=default&eurl=http%3A%2F%2Frapgenius%2Ecom&hl=en_US
```

Which, when curled, gives this response:

```
status=fail&errorcode=150&reason=This+video+contains+content+from+UMG%2C+who+has+blocked+it+from+display+on+this+website.%3Cbr%2F%3E%3Cu%3E%3Ca+href%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D_kmeFXjjGfk%26feature%3Dplayer_embedded%27+target%3D%27_blank%27%3EWatch+on+YouTube%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fu%3E&fslarge=1
```

So maybe I can just query this URL? Will this work in all cases? Is there an "official" way of doing this?

Comment: I have never used Rap Genius, but from what info you provide, the only thing that comes to my mind that YouTube could be using to transmit this information is the `HTTP_REFERER` header (which will contain a Rap Genius URL). Might be worth playing around with that

Answer (score 1):

I had the error:

> This video contains content from XXX

I noticed I was using https when requesting the page containing the embedded video. Switching back to http seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have all the info in  http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&q=_kmeFXjjGfk

"status":{"value":"restricted","reason":"limitedSyndication"},"restrictions":[{"type":"country","relationship":"deny","countries":"DE"}]

March 19, 2013 -- Response is now quite different than that given above:

{"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"updated":"2013-03-19T14:47:14.533Z","totalItems":0,"startIndex":1,"itemsPerPage":25}}

Comment: It seems like it no longer contains the restriction info.